# Final Year project Proxy Blocker Guidance

Tags: java, proxy

I am a MSC IT final year student and I am thinking to develop a proxy blocker.
Proxy blocker is like if any one is accessing my site (mysite.com) via a proxy site, then the site should not be opened.
Please if any one can give me some guide lines to start this project.

I am actually confused that from which phase should I start..
I am having no idea about proxy blocking.
Please if any one can help.

Or if any one can suggest some another topic for me.
I can work on JAVA, Jsp JSF ASP.NET..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Http Server module development (with C) would be the title of your question. You can best restrict access' over proxies via apache mods using a black list of best known proxies worldwide.